# 「浮き彫り」の意味・使い方がよくわからない

Tags: meaning

日本語の授業の単語を復習しているところですが、「浮き彫り」という言葉が出てきました。
フラッシュカードに書いてあったのは「to be distinct」ですが、辞書を参照したら「throw something into relief」とか「a relief」とあります。

例えば（マック辞書から）

> ▸ 闇の中で白い仮面がくっきりと浮き彫りにされた
>   The white mask stood out in bold relief in the dark.
>
> ▸ これで疑獄の深刻さが浮き彫りにされた
>   This threw the seriousness of the scandal into relief.

使い方と実際の意味がわかりません。reliefは法律用語ですか？法律に全然関係していない例文もあるので。

Comment: Are you a native English speaker? Do you know all the meanings of the word "relief"? Just wondering if you might not be considering "relief" in art as: *the projection of forms or figures from a flat ground, so that they are partly or wholly free of it*.

Comment: I don't think that definition of relief is in the average English speaker's consciousness regardless

Comment: I didn't get your comment. You mean is not a matter of being native or not, it is not common for people to know that definition anyway?

Comment: It is not common for people to know that definition of "relief," I'm pretty sure. I know it exists but I didn't know if it was applicable here, since there's an entry in the dictionary like 浮き彫りになる or something

Comment: Oh ok, got it. To be honest, I also didn't think of that immediately. It was the kanji 彫 that made me do the logical connection.

Comment: As a native English speaker, I only learned of that word when learning about art history in the Renaissance. It appears though the idiom might not be as common as I thought though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of relief in question isn't disaster relief, it's a [type of sculpture called a relief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relief). There is also a related English idiom [to bring/throw into sharp/stark relief](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/throw+into+sharp+relief), which means to distinguish something via contrasting it to another object. Presumably, this definition is abstracted from the process of making a relief sculpture, where the sculpture is in sharp contrast to the rock.

Let's look at the Japanese definitions for 浮き彫り (from [Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%B5%AE%E3%81%8D%E5%BD%AB%E3%82%8A)):

> ① 平らな面に模様や形が浮き出すように彫り上げた彫刻。うきあげぼり。レリーフ。
>
> ② ほかのものと区別してそれとはっきりわかること。「争点が－になった」 「両者の違いが－になる」

We can see that the first definition refers to the sculptural relief and the second definition is very similar to the English idiom.